# BaseClass unable to find its subclasses

Tags: python, dynamic, python-import, base-class

I have a bunch of feature classes spread over a few modules all inherit from a BaseFeature class. Somehow the BaseFeature is unable to know its sublcasses by calling the subclasses() method.

In another module e.g. (pipeline.py) I only import the BaseFeature class.
Then I call BaseFeature.**subclasses**() on the class object, not an actual object of the BaseFeature!
Somehow the call returns nothing. But when I additionally import feature_x.py into pipeline.py the BaseFeature knows its subclasses again.
I want avoid that because of dynamic module importing.

inside pipeline.py:

```
from base_feature import BaseFeature

class Pipeline:

    def init_features:
        feature_classes_list = BaseFeature.__subclasses__()
        print(feature_classes_list)

        # loop for init features in feature_classes_list
```

[] - empty list

But:

```
import feature_x
import feature_y
```

then repeat the feature initiation, the BaseFeature "knows" its sublcasses again.

```
[<class feature_x>, <class feature_y>]
```

I want to avoid a separate feature module import because they are a lot. And not all are needed every time. 
So why is the BaseClass not knowing of its sublasses?

Comment: Method docs read: "Each class keeps a list of weak references to its immediate subclasses. This method returns a list of all those references still alive" Your references are neither "alive" nor "referenced" until you import them. You can tweak the import machinery to provide some kind of auto-import feature, but either way plain use of `__subclasses` won't solve your issue

Comment: @yorodm thank you, at least it seems right now, that there is no "fancier" way to acheive that.

Comment: You **could** implement some kind of auto import, but people will hate you for it :D